# Error Message from OBD-II (7F 01 11)

Tags: engine, toyota, obd-ii, electronic-control-module

I have been extracting OBD-II DATA from UART board (ELM327) on my TOYOTA INNOVA. It responded correctly few weeks before and gave all supported sensor values. But now, for every response, ECU responds **"7F 01 11"**. Please tell me what exactly this output means and how to get rid of this problem

Comment: It means the requested PID is not known

Comment: @JuannStrauss lets take 010C, a standard PID. Why is that when we tried before, the car responded correctly but now not responding . How can we get it fixed? IS that because of some changes in ELM327 (UART Board)

Comment: I can't say without seeing your code, but it may be that your header has changed or you're requesting the wrong mode. Or maybe you changed the baud rate.

Comment: @JuannStrauss I did change the Headers through ATSH XXX when i was monitoring CAN DATA through ATMA. Then i did reset it many times through ATZ and ATD, is there any other way to reset ELM to original state like with Headers off or reset.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I've only done it via a C# library and a piece of software I wrote on top of it. You can have a look at the library here if you want: http://obdcsharpwrapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JuannStrauss : Could you compile the comments to this question as a generic answer for containing possible reasons? I want to move this question out of the "Unanswered" territory

Answer (score 1):

7F = general fail response.

11 = Service Not Supported.

That is the meaning. It's odd that it was working before.  Ultimately, it could be the device that you are using to read the codes is defective.